# CSS :hover Selector not working correctly

Tags: css, hover

The :hover selector is used to select elements but not working this,

im try this  but not working, how can i fix it
Thanks

```
.btn btn:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-primary" Height="30px" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is wrong:

```
.btn:hover { /* btn:hover is missing class selector the dot. */
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,  its working